# Game of Life cells as subpixels on an HTML canvas

Tags: leaflet, html5-canvas, conways-game-of-life

My Game of Life implementation displays cells on a canvas, using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) to allow zooming and panning. At the highest zoom level, one cell corresponds to one pixel. But after zooming out once, 4 cells with coordinates (x,y); (x+1,y); (x,y+1); (x+1,y+1) correspond to the same pixel. If one of these cells is born,

```js
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

makes the pixel black, if the cell later dies,

```js
ctx.clearRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

makes the pixel grey, not white again. This is also demonstrated by the following HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.setTransform(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
  <canvas width="1" height="1"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Filling a rectangle that covers less than one pixel and then clearing it again leaves the pixel grey.

In order to issue `clearRect` commands that cover a whole pixel, I would have to consider the status of all 2<sup>2n</sup> cells at zoom level n when one of them dies. Are there better alternatives? My data structure is such that I look at only three x coordinates in parallel at any time.

(My [code](https://bitbucket.org/HeikoTheissen/life/src/b396838a9d346a5de0e7e5235f448af9519082e5/life.js#lines-388:400) currently contains a `clearPixel` option that clears the pixel already if *any* of the 2<sup>2n</sup> cells dies, because this looks somewhat better to me than the alternative.)

Comment: You gotta keep track of the whole state of the grid.

Comment: Yes, but when one cell dies, I don't at the moment consider other cells 2n x coordinates away. Can I avoid this?

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect again, carefully. Consider restating your problem.

Comment: My problem is the behavior of `clearRect` if the rectangle covers less than one pixel. I have tried to express that better in my question now.

Comment: *Maybe* you should be looking at [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). If your question is more about what data structure offers lowest computational complexity to query if a supercell of size 2^2n has at least one "on" cell, then you must consider as well the computational complexity of other processes being run on your grid, i.e. how costly it is to run an iteration of the Conway algorithm.